# Solace messaging mock connection object - how

Tags: scala, mocking, jms, scalatest, solace-mq

I am using scala unit test(maven) with solace messaging. Use cases are publish message and consume message. 
Question : Is there any standalone way(runs with maven life cycle from different environments like DEV, QA etc.. ) to mock solace connection object to test my publish and consume messages from the solace JMS queue?

Answer (score 2):

Java Message Service(JMS) is an open standard. 
Therefore, you can make use of any JMS mocking tools to perform this mock-up.

Comment: any examples for mocking jms connection object ?

Comment: any suggestions and examples mocking tools to mock jms connection queues you have ?